# Orchard CMS add menu from module creation

Tags: navigation, orchardcms

I have created a module (still lots of work to do to make it production-ready, but moving ahead).

Anyway, I would like the module (which is basically an MVC app a la Orchard webshop from Skywalker) to create automatically a menu item for viewing a page from the module. I tried MainMenu.cs first, but this one created the entry as first entry, no matter what position I gave in the code. And also it would be a hassle if you wanted to have the menu on another position to compile first a new release.

So now I just created a meny item manually in the dashboard pointing to //.

Is there a way to automate this within the module, and have it in such a way that the customer can change the position afterwards from the admin module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, menu entries are added from code, typically, so it would be trivial to use dynamic values in there rather than static ones. There are examples of that in Vandelay.Industries in fact. What's under the New menu is another.

Comment: I'll check Vandelay. Do you happen to have a link. I'll search Google otherwise

Comment: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries